# Read json data from covid19 api using python

Tags: python, json, api

I was trying to import timeseries data from link [Covid_data](https://api.covid19india.org/v4/min/timeseries.min.json) to get the daily historical and 7 day moving average data.But my code doesn't work. I am new to this so maybe my key value pair is not correct. The structure of the file is given here [json_structure_link](https://api.covid19india.org/documentation/timeseries.min.html).

**My Code**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://api.covid19india.org/v4/min/timeseries.min.json")
if response.status_code == 200:
    historical_day_numbers = response.json()
    DATE = []
    STATE = []
    TOTAL_CASES = []
    RECOVERED = []
    DECEASED = []
    TESTED = []
    VACCINATED = []
    
   
    for state in historical_day_numbers.keys():
        STATE.append(state)
        DATE.append(historical_day_numbers[state]["dates"])
        TOTAL_CASES.append(historical_day_numbers[state]["dates"]["delta"]["confirmed"])
        RECOVERED.append(historical_day_numbers[state]["dates"]["delta"]["recovered"])
        DECEASED.append(historical_day_numbers[state]["dates"]["delta"]["deceased"])
        TESTED.append(historical_day_numbers[state]["dates"]["delta"]["tested"])
        VACCINATED.append(historical_day_numbers[state]["dates"]["delta"]["vaccinated"])
        
    Covid19_historical_data = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            
            "STATE/UT": STATE,
            "DATE": DATE,
            "TOTAL_CASES": TOTAL_CASES,
            "RECOVERED": RECOVERED,
            "DECEASED": DECEASED,
            "TESTED": TESTED,
            "VACCINATED": VACCINATED,
            
        }
    )
    #print(data.head())

else:
    print("Error while calling API: {}".format(response.status_code, response.reason))
```

**The error I am getting**

```
KeyError: 'delta'
```

But I see the delta present.

Comment: Looks like you've misunderstood the JSON structure. Their is no 'delta' key available directly from the 'dates' key. The 'dates' key reveals a JSON that has key(s) such as '2020-03-26'. You can use that key to reveal the structure that contains the 'delta*' keys

Comment: @DarkKnight, I am not sure how to call the keys which are part of dates key

Comment: You're going to have to completely rethink your approach. Each date key has values that vary from date to date. The delta, delta7 and total keys don't always exists. Furthermore, within those keys not all have values for confirmed, recovered or tested. The best think to do is prettyprint the JSON response. That will make it easier to read and understand

Comment: @DarkKnight, ok let me try . Thanks!

Comment: @DarkKnight. This helped, I was able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
historical_day_numbers[state]['dates'].keys()
Output: dict_keys(['2020-04-06', '2020-04-07', '2020-04-08', '2020-04-09', '2020-04-10', '2020-04-11', '2020-04-12', '2020-04-13', '2020-04-14', '2020-04-15', '2020-04-16', '2020-04-17', '2020-04-18', '2020-04-19', '2020-04-20', '2020-04-21',...])
```

When you type, you will realize that there is a key for each date and there is no key called 'delta' here.

If you edit your code as follows, you will not get this error.

```
historical_day_numbers[state]['dates']['2021-07-25']['delta']
```